# XLConnect does not load in R 3.5.0

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

I am trying to load the XLConnect package and cannot get it to load.

I get the follow error when I run:

```
library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
```

I tried to install rJava and XLConnectJars but I keep getting the same message.

I am pretty new to this can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Someone may provide some help on getting your Java configured, but if it's an option for you, you might consider packages like **openxlsx** that don't have such a thorny dependency. If you only need to _read_ xlsx files, **readxl** would be another option.

Comment: (1) make sure you have the rJava package installed `install.packages("rJava"); (2) check the type of Java installed on your local machine, is it 32-bit or 64-bit? I had to switch to 64-bit in the past to make it work. (3) manually download and install XLConnectJars from CRAN

Comment: So I just installed the latest version of Java (64-bit). I have been trying to use XLConnect to import multiple sheets at once since I have a couple huge xls files to work with. I've been googling and checking here to get rJava and XLConnect to work. I keep getting this same error for rJava, XLConnect, and XLConnectJars

Comment: After installing Java you may need to run `R CMD javareconf`